# foreach loop and send it by mail

Tags: php, mysql, email

I would like to send a mail with an overview of the last 30 days. Everybody should get a mail based on the field "lastname".

The script works so far but everyone gets a mail for one line and not collected.

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

error_reporting(E_STRICT | E_ALL);

date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

require ("/usr/share/php/libphp-phpmailer/autoload.php");

$mysql = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');
mysqli_select_db($mysql, 'verein');
$query = 'SELECT OrderId, date, firstname, lastname, name, menge, Stueckpreis, Gesamt from orders_products, customers, products WHERE orders_products.Kundenid = customers.k_id AND orders_products.Productid = products.p_id AND date >= now() - INTERVAL 30 DAY ORDER BY OrderId DESC';
$result = $mysql->query($query);

foreach ($result as $row){

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host       = ''; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true; //SMTP connection will not close after each email sent, reduces SMTP overhead
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Username   = '';                     //SMTP username
$mail->Password   = '';      //SMTP password
$mail->setFrom(', '');
$mail->addReplyTo('@', 'Information');
$mail->AddAddress(''); 


//Content
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'Test Mail';
        $mail->Body = "Hallo " . $row['firstname']. " ". $row['lastname']. ",<br><br>;
        
$mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
```

How I can make it so that the output on the key lastname is distinguished and everyone gets only one mail with his bookings?

Comment: with data and wanted result we could understand what you mean by collected? the every customer  gets one email?

Comment: That's invalid code btw. Don't send the mail inside the loop, gather all information your need in a variable and send email _after_ the loop

Comment: "everyone gets a mail for one line and not collected" - what does that mean? Also, is this a mail problem, or a MySQL problem?